# Trying to pass an array to my class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I am having trouble passing an array to my sorting classes because i need to sort the same array with two different algorithms. I am getting the error

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
- The constructor Mergesort() is undefined
- Syntax error on token "originalArray", delete 
 this token
```

The code

```
class sorterProgram {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Declares instances of the sorting classes

    int[] originalArray = new int[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        originalArray[i] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    }
    Quicksort q = new Quicksort(originalArray);
    Mergesort m = new Mergesort(originalArray);
    //declares keyboard to accept user input for type of sort
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //choice set as one so the do-while and if statements will start
    int choice = 1;
    // loop that does sorting untill the user is done


    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the # to start the sort of a 500 Element Array: \n1: Quicksort then Mergesort \n2: Exit");
        //only works if the user chooses the correct numbers
        if (1 == choice || choice == 2) {
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Before Quicksort");
            q.print();
            long timeQuicksort = System.nanoTime();
            q.quicksort();
            long completedInQuicksort = System.nanoTime() - timeQuicksort;
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("After Quicksort ");
            q.print();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Before Mergesort");
            m.print();
            long timeMergesort = System.nanoTime();
            m.sort();
            long completedInMergesort = System.nanoTime() - timeMergesort;
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("After Mergesort ");
            m.print();

            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Time took to complete Quicksort (nanoseconds): "+ completedInQuicksort);
            System.out.println("Time took to complete Mergesort (nanoseconds): "+ completedInMergesort);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Thanks for using the Quicksort and Mergesort");

        }

    } while (choice != 2);

}
}
```

and these are my two sorter constructors

```
class Quicksort {
int array[];
int size;

public Quicksort(int[] n) {
    size = n.length;
    // create array for merge sorting with size n+1
    array = new int[n.length + 1];
    // assign value into the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        n[i] = array[i];
    }

class Mergesort {

private int size;
private int[] array;
private int[] tempMergeArray;

public Mergesort(int[] n) {

    size = n.length;
    // create array for merge sorting with size n+1
    array = new int[n.length + 1];
    // assign value into the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        n[i] = array[i];
    }

    // set the last value as a big value so the sorting ends properly
    array[n.length] = 99999;
}
```

EDIT: i have it passing now but they are just passing zeros

Comment: Please review array, variable, and method invocation syntax. What do you think this `new Mergesort(int[] originalArray[] );` does and why?

Comment: it wants me to put just originalArray but that just passes zeros into the program.

Comment: Fix your syntax errors so that your program compiles. Use a debugger to find your program bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Quicksort q = new Quicksort(int [] originalArray[]);
Mergesort m = new Mergesort(int[] originalArray[] );
```

to

```
Quicksort q = new Quicksort(originalArray);
Mergesort m = new Mergesort(originalArray);
```

and inside both of your constructors, change

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    n[i] = array[i];
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    array[i] = n[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing arrays as variables into functions and constructors there is the same syntax as if you were passing in a normal variable.

Correct:

```
int[] myArray = new int[12];
myObject.myFunction(myArray);
```

Incorrect:

```
int[] myArray = new int[12];
myObject.myFunction(int[] myArray[]);
```

You may want to review [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), it will help you with using arrays in java.

Also, you may want to make sure that they are in the same package. Based on your lack of a `package my.package;` it looks like you have the classes in a default package. This is bad because then you cannot import them from a seperate package ex. classes in `org.myamazingapplication` cannot do `import myclass` (assuming myclass is in the default package). Also many apis such as [bukkit](http://dl.bukkit.org/) require a package to be used.